# Enviar variable por Intent desde Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Kotlin, logré conectar una API REST con la APP. Hice uso del RecyclerView pero tengo el problema de que no puedo enviar una variable mediante Intent. Espero alguien pueda explicarme como realizarlo ya que no sé si deba hacerlo desde el Adapter o desde el Activity

```
package com.santalucila.reparto

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.cliente.view.*

class ClienteAdapter(private val clientes:List<cliente>): RecyclerView.Adapter<ClienteAdapter.ClienteViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ClienteViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.cliente, parent, false)
        return ClienteViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return clientes.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ClienteViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.nombre.text = clientes[position].nombre
        holder.itemView.direccion.text = clientes[position].direccion
        holder.itemView.descripcion.text = clientes[position].descripcion
        holder.itemView.codcliente.text = clientes[position].codcliente.toString()
    }

    class ClienteViewHolder(val view: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        init {
            view.ver_mas.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(view.context, ClienteCompletoActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("codcliente", "AQUI QUIERO PASAR UN DATO DEL HOLDER")
                view.context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podría recomendar que lo pases a través del activity.

Razon:

Recordemos que para iniciar el intent `Intent(view.context, ClienteCompletoActivity::class.java)` y también `view.context.startActivity(intent)` , se necesita un context. En este caso le estas pasando un context de un item de tu adapter. Puede funcionar, pero estas en un contexto de items-adapter -> activity. De primera vista parece que no hay un problema. Pero ahora imagines este caso. No solo quieres lanzar un intent, sino también quieres obtener un resultado. Por lo tanto ya no usarás `startActivity` sino un `startActivityForResult`. Entonces, en el viewHolder no puedes mandar esta instrucción porque el context debe ser del activity, por lo tanto tendrías que mandar el context de un activity o fragment. En caso realizas es`startActivityForResult` con el context del activity, entonces se lanzará la respuesta en el método `onActivityResult`  del activity mas no el del fragment. De caso contrario, si realizar un `startActivityForResult`  con el context del fragment, se lanzará el método `onActivityResult`  del fragment mas no del activity. Si bien para el caso que presentas no tiene mucha relevancia, seria una recomendación lanzarlo desde la activity.

Espero te ayude :)